# next_post_link() on custom menu structure

Tags: menus, next-post-link, sub-menu

In a blog, I am using `next_post_link()` and `prev_post_link()` extensively on posts.

I also have a number of pages that I show in a WP3 menu. They are organized in topics and sub-topics e.g. like so:

```
Home
About
- Subpage 1
- Subpage 2 
- Subpage 3 
Contact
```

I would like to set up a "previous" and "next" navigation on these pages as well, so that when I'm on "About"'s Subpage 2, I can navigate to Subpages 1 and 3 using the "next" and "previous" arrows.

The default behaviour of `next_post_link()`/`prev_post_link()` doesn't work for this: It calculates the next and previous items based on the list of *all* pages.

Is there an easy way to make `next_post_link()` and `prev_post_link()` sensitive to my menu structure, or will I have to build this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The function behind the function behind the function…

`next_post_link();` is a wrapper for `adjacent_post_link();` which then calls `get_adjacent_post();` where the 3<sup>rd</sup> argument is `$previous` and set to `true/false` to get the previous or next post.

This gives you two opportunities: Use the output or the query filter.

#### Output filter

This might sound easier, but you'll have to do an extra query for this.

```
// The core:
$adjacent = $previous ? 'previous' : 'next';
echo apply_filters( "{$adjacent}_post_link", $format, $link );

// Add your callbacks like this:
add_filter( 'previous_post_link', 'your_callback_fn', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'next_post_link', 'your_callback_fn', 20, 2 );
```

#### Query filter

This is what I'd recommend you: Check whether there's `$post->post_parent` set and then modify the query to get the post with the next higher id that has the same parent.

```
// The core:
$adjacent = $previous ? 'previous' : 'next';
$join  = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_join", $join, $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories );
$where = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_where", $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_date $op %s AND p.post_type = %s AND p.post_status = 'publish' $posts_in_ex_cats_sql", $current_post_date, $post->post_type), $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories );
$sort  = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_sort", "ORDER BY p.post_date $order LIMIT 1" );
```

Comment: made me laugh "The function behind the function behind the function…" I was just looking at this yesterday for another question on WPSE. I took one look at the queries and went "Hell no!"

Comment: :) About the query: Shouldn't be too hard. `AND p.post_parent = %s` where `%s` then is `$post->post_parent` or something close to that.

Comment: Cool. Thanks very much, this gives me a starting point!